# using ETag but the status code is always 200 and not 304

Tags: java, facebook, google-app-engine, etag, required

When I try to request for the the 
http://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=friends
with the ETag I always get the request code as 200 every time.
we I made two back to back response and checked it. The change was at the end it had a section for pagination and it attached a access token. which is always different so the ETag value also changes.
I am using google app engine to host my app. and using **URLFetech** to make the request.

```
<code> 
String ETag = FBUser.getProperty("ETag").toString();<br>
String s="https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=friendlists&access_token=" + facebookSignedRequest.getOauth_token();<br>
URL u = null;<br>
try {<br>
u = new URL(s);<br>
} catch (MalformedURLException e) 
{
e.printStackTrace(out1);}<br>           
FetchOptions options = FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults();<br>
HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest(u,HTTPMethod.GET,options);<br>
req.addHeader(new HTTPHeader("If-None-Match", ETag));<br>
URLFetchService service = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();<br>
HTTPResponse res = null;<br>
try 
{res = service.fetch(req);} <br>
catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(out1);}<br>

String newETag="";<br>
List<HTTPHeader> Head = res.getHeaders();<br>
for(int i=0;i < Head.size();i++)<br>
{
if("ETag".equals(Head.get(i).getName()))<br>
{
   newETag=Head.get(i).getValue();<br>
   out1.println("new ETag : " + newETag);<br>
   out1.println("ETag" + ETag);<br>
}
}
if(res.getResponseCode() == 304)<br>
{ 
  return false;<br>
}else
{
FBUser.setProperty("ETag", newETag);<br>
datastore.put(FBUser);<br>
return true;<br>
}
</code>
```

regards,
iDeViL17

Comment: If the ETag changes then you will not get a 304.

Comment: Thats what I am not able to figure out why the ETag is changing.

Comment: You're going to have to show us relevant code.

Comment: I have the same problem even I try to use RESTClient Add-on. Also I tried Firebug and Modify Headers Add-on as mentioned here https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/627/ but the same problem. I received 200 response code in each request even I set the header correctly. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I try now with request. All works:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=...
```

First request.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse = httpClient.execute(get);   
Header[] headers = httpResponse.getHeaders("ETag");   
if (headers != null && headers.length() > 0)
   etags = headers[0].getValue();
```

Second request:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = HttpGet(url);
get.addHeader("If-None-Match", etags);
HttpResponse = httpClient.execute(get);
```